# Ubuntu 16.04 some app windows do not show

Tags: ubuntu, xrandr, display

I have just installed **Ubuntu 16.04** in a PC board. The fact is that after upgrading to kernel 4.4.0-28-generic I cannot see the windows of some applications I need to use, just as Synaptic and Eclipse. In the latter case, I tried with Eclipse Luna and Eclipse Neon and configuring the session as indicated in other threads (e.g. [Link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/java-common/+bug/1552764))

**/* EDIT 1 */**

The xrandr ouput of that board is, in **Ubuntu 14.04 LTS**:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 2048 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP2 connected primary 1024x600+0+168 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 300mm x 200mm
   1024x600       60.0*+
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA1 connected 1024x768+1024+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 304mm x 228mm
   1024x768       60.0*+   75.1     74.8     70.1  
   800x600        72.2     75.0     60.3     56.2  
   640x480        75.0     72.8     60.0  
   720x400        70.1  
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Furthermore, in **Ubuntu 16.04 LTS**:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 2048 x 776, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected 1024x600+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 300mm x 200mm
   1024x600      60.00*+
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   640x480       59.94  
   512x300       60.00  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA1 connected primary 1024x768+1024+8 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 304mm x 228mm
   1024x768      60.00*+  75.08    74.79    70.07  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    60.00  
   720x400       70.08  
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

I am working with 1024x768 resolution.

After some trouble I tested a Ubuntu 14.04 LTS distribution...and the effect was the same! For instance, Firefox opens correctly, but Synaptic nor Eclipse do.

Maybe is it any issue related to GTK ? Is there any solution/patch for this problem?

Comment: Silly question, but do you have an external screen attached, but switched off? If not, please add the output of `xrandr` to your question.

Comment: You *seem* to have two screens attached, but DP2 shows no options. Are both switched on (or does DP2 even exist)? Pretty sure your windows appear on this (phantom?) screen, since it is the primary and the left one. Please mention.

Comment: Could you please mention if the screen is attached (seem so) and switched on or off? It is really essential information to give an answer. Nothing to do with Gtk.

Comment: For instance, in U16, I have 'Built-in Display' and 'AD electronics 15" ', which is the current monitor. If I disable any of them in the Displays screen, or select 'Mirror displays' the OS is frozen and I can do nothing but reboot :S. I tried even moving the monitor to the left side without luck

Comment: I mean, is there *actually* (physically) a monitor attached?

Comment: Yes, there is one monitor connected to the VGA output and powered on, which corresponds to the VGA1 entries in xrandr